# Unable to active windows store app .Unknown error:0x80040200

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

[image: Screenshot of error message]

This Project was based on Windows10 IoTCore "Hello World"Damo.I Want to show Image by pure rgb bytes array.So I added my code in this.

```
public async void Func()
    {
        int ret;
        uint mode, x, y, width, height;
        mode = x = y = width = height = 0;
        ret = Roseek_ImageAcquisition_GetResolution(ref mode, ref x, ref y, ref width, ref height);
        RunFlag = true;
        uint buffsize = width * height * 3;
        RawFrameInfo frameinfo = new RawFrameInfo();
        byte[] Framebytes = new byte[buffsize];
        byte[] bgra = new byte[width * height * 4];
        while (RunFlag)
        {
            ret = Roseek_ImageAcquisition_FetchFrame(Framebytes, buffsize, ref frameinfo, 1000);
            if (ret == 0)
            {
                pFrameToRGB(Framebytes, bgra, (int)width, (int)height);
                /*                    IBuffer ibuf = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(width * height * 4);
                                    bgra.CopyTo(ibuf);

                                    SoftwareBitmap image = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(ibuf, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)width, (int)height, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore);
                                    SoftwareBitmapSource sf = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
                                   await sf.SetBitmapAsync(image);*/
                using (IRandomAccessStream RandomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
                {
                    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, RandomAccessStream);
                    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, width, height, 96, 96, bgra);
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();
                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, async () =>
                    {
                        var image = new BitmapImage();
                        await image.SetSourceAsync(RandomAccessStream);
                    }) ;

                }

                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
               {
                   HelloMessage.Text = "While Loop! FetchFrame OK!";
               });
            }


        }
```

Some "Roseek" functions are from another DLLs. I think that some wrong codes may be added in while Loop. I debuged this App many times and it's OK.  When I modified and continue to remote debuge this App ,some sample err like “Memery out" happened.After that,I can't active App forever, but App was installed in IoT device. I try what i can do like restart or uninstalling App,but not work.
I'm a green hand about developing UWP on IoTCore. So can I ask that some wrong code I added in loop?

Comment: I used Fun()  by Task and Task.start()

Comment: Can you debug this app on desktop after this issue happened? When did error "memory out" occur? Can you show some detailed info?

Comment: Yes,and not any error . But location debug environment is not same as remote debug environment. When i debuging this app in location , i found that the process memery of app  is more and more big,even bigger than 5g. So I think the wrong code is my first problem . I will remote debug app again after modified this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the very same error when using VS2017 / Xamarin whatEver template & UWP The app loads to the phone and then it crashes.
So I would say that there is nothing wrong with your code. Winphones are not supported anymore by MS  ;)

Answer (score 0):

On my not supported Winphone restarting it made it working again